# django requset.body лишний слеш

Tags: python, django

Отправляю себе на сервер (через postman) следующую строку:

```
{"body":"\xfb","nick":"Nikita_Belochkin"}
```

Делаю `print(request.body)`
и вижу `b'{"body":"\\xfb","nick":"Nikita_Belochkin"}'`

Почему появился лишний слеш? Из-за него я не могу декодировать свою строку:

```
byte_str = b'{"body":"\\xfb","nick":"Nikita_Belochkin"}'
byte_str.decode(encoding='cp1251')
print(byte_str)
{"body":"\xfb","nick":"Nikita_Belochkin"}
```

А вот если там нет лишнего слеша, то все хорошо:

```
byte_str = b'{"body":"\xfb","nick":"Nikita_Belochkin"}'
byte_str.decode(encoding='cp1251')
print(byte_str)
{"body":"ы","nick":"Nikita_Belochkin"}
```

Comment: Он не лишний, ваш слеш специально экранируется вторым слэшем перед выводом строкового литерала, потому что в строковых литералах слеш имеет специальное значение, и это специальное значение нужно отключить для сохранения слеша. Если вы через postman отправили этот слеш, то python и django обязаны предпринять все возможные действия по сохранению этого слеша, вот они и предпринимают. Если пришло `\xfb` — они и сохраняют этот `\xfb` в исходном виде. Если вы хотите отправить букву «ы» — отправляйте букву «ы», а не слеш.

Comment: Правда, похоже, Postman поддерживает использование только кодировки UTF-8. У вас есть какая-то веская причина использовать устаревшую cp1251?